# axios request header not set after page refresh with vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

So, I ran into a problem.

I have a vue frontend which calls api on laravel. To deal with a page refresh to automatically login the user again if the token is still valid I store it in my local storage.

However once I refresh the page the header isnt set. I have to go on page back in my app (simple button with vue-router) and then it works again.

This is the code I am using

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if(token !== null) {
    const bearerToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    const bearer = "Bearer " + bearerToken.token;
    config.headers.Authorization = bearer;
  }
    return config
})
```

The localStorage containing the token is there 100%. It sits in my main.js, so there is 0 chance it doesnt get loaded. Yet, when I put console.log("set header") in my axios.interceptor it doesnt get called upon page refresh as well. Am I overlooking sth?

Comment: as follow up, one thing I noticed: once I wait until I have my response from the server back from my autom login and watch the state to be true in via a watcher and then fire my request it works. This concludes with my observation in the network tab that the api request fires before I get my user data back. While not optimal I can fix that but it still doesnt make sense to me that the header isnt set on page refresh

Comment: you can do like this `window.axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;`   put this in your `master.vue` page so everytime refresh it set header

Comment: Doesnt work sadly. It gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined". This leads me to the assumption axios isnt defined when I call it. However I import it in the same file and initialize it with Vue.use. However that doesnt make any sense since I can login without any issues

Comment: yes you need to create a window.axio = require ('axios') then use

Comment: Ok. Fixed it.... however I dont know how and why. I just put my header definition into my App.vue component under created. But shouldnt this work with main.js as well?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Axios defaults in the router/index.